# install spyder for python3.4 ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.4, spyder

I ned to install spyder for python 3.4. 
I used [this link](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-on-linux)
with the following code

Requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-sphinx
```

Installing:

```
sudo pip install spyder
```

Updating:

```
sudo pip install -U spyder
```

But when I run spyder it opens python 2.7

Since the only one that shows the number of python is the first one, I guess the issue is related with sphinx (but don't know).

How can I link spyder to python 3.4 instead of 2.7?

Comment: download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py then run `sudo  python3 get-pip.py`, then `pip3/pip3.4 install your_package ` but pip3.4 should have been  installed by default with python3.4

Comment: @PadraicCunningham your solution worked.

Comment: good glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Install with pip3 instead of pip. It may be beneficial to work in an isolated python 3 environment such as a venv, remember the system python is python 2. Have a look at the [Dockerfile I use to set up my environment](https://github.com/garry-cairns/environments/blob/master/python/Dockerfile) to see if that helps.

Using pip3's full path when calling it will also probably help. I'm on my phone rather than laptop so can't confirm right now.

Comment: sudo: pip3: command not found... and I already have installed this: sudo apt-get install python3-pip.

Comment: Have you apt-get installed python 3 dev?

Comment: you mean sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev? Yes, I have. and still get the same error.

Comment: see my edits. The file I've linked to produces a python 3 environment that might be suitable.

Comment: python3-dev has nothing to do with a pip command not being found

Comment: to deal with such version problem the best approach is using virtualenvs (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)